# How can I run Python on iPad Pro?

Tags: python, ios, ipad, pythonista

How can I run Python on an iPad Pro?

Answer (score 1):

If not a dedicated app, you could always use an online python compiler in the iPad's browser.

For example:

- https://repl.it/languages/python3
- https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler
- https://paiza.io/en/projects/new?language=python3

Answer (score 1):

**Carnets** is a complete package app for running Python on iPads.

This free App is around 510 MB and can run Jupyter notebook.

You can install all packages of python just by writing `pip install " Package name "` like numpy or matplotlib, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that any library that contains e.g. Fortran code can only be installed by the developer of the app, only pure Python libraries can the loaded by the user. This severely limits the use of such apps as Carnets, JUNO, Pythonista, etc.
I am surprised that the ‚Python community‘ does not create such an app, which would be updated regularly with libraries containing compiled code.